# Debugging a simple C++ executable using MSBuild from command prompt

Tags: c++, c++11, cmd, msbuild

I have a C++ executable compiled using MSBuild from command prompt after configuring the project with CMake. I need to be debug it. Is it possible to debug it from Windows command prompt (cmd) using MSBuild and how can I do it? I do not want to use the Visual Studio GUI.

Comment: Care to share why you don't want to use the VS debugging? It's actually quite good and definitely a smaller learning curve than command-line counterparts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSBuild controls the build process. It cannot be used to debug an application. If you want to debug an application without using Visual Studio, you can use one of the command-line based debuggers ([WinDbg, KD, CDB, NTSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index)).

An introduction to using WinDbg can be found at [Getting Started with WinDbg (User-Mode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg).